# Can I make PyInstaller optimize the compilation?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

When I use PyInstaller, it builds my modules as .pyc files.  But I'd prefer it to run the compilation with -OO to optmize and remove docstrings.  Is this possible?

Comment: i am not sure, but i think it is not (yet?) possible. in the docs they only mention `v` `u` and `W` options: https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#giving-run-time-python-options

Comment: but maybe you can compile to pyc yourself with -OO and pass the optimized pyc file to pyinstaller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `pyinstaller` is a Python script, it is sufficient to run it with optimisation activated: e.g.

```
PYTHONOPTIMIZE=2 pyinstaller script.py
```

so that during bundling `.pyo` files are created instead of `.pyc`

Comment: This works - but note to anyone reading, that PyInstaller archive extractors will probably call the optimized file .pyc, causing lots of confusion.  However, it's easy to check the docstring is absent.

Answer (score 1):

i would like to add that in cmd.exe you can type

```
>set PYTHONOPTIMIZE=1
>pyinstaller skript.py
```

the answer from Stefano M did not work in my console. i had to make two different calls.

you can check if your code is optimized by using the preprocessor directive

```
if __debug__:
    print("optimized")
```